# Google not showing homepage meta except for one search

Tags: seo, google

I'm just starting off with SEO and helping my brother with his website. 
Now, there were no meta details on the site whatsoever, and around a month ago I added some to the homepage. 
When you search the company name, it shows the description I've put. 
However, if you search something else, and the **homepage** shows up in the serps, it will NOT show me the meta details. How is this possible? I know that Google doesn't always show the Meta info, but why only when I search for the company directly and NONE of the other results? 
Hope someone can shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google usually only shows the meta description if it contains the keywords for which the user searched.  You must be using the company name in the meta description you  wrote, but you are probably not using the other keywords for which you are searching in the meta description.

For example.  Your site could be called "Bob's Beach Toys".    And your meta description could be "Buy a wide selection play equipment to use at the ocean from Bob's Beach Toys."   Then the meta description would be used for

- bobs beach toys
- bobs toys
- beach toys

but not for

- bobs sand bucket
- beach shovel and rake

A few years ago Google was using the meta description for almost all searches.   That just isn't the case today.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand now... the other poster tried to explain the same thing but my brain was still being stubborn.

Answer (score 0):

If the meta tag is correctly placed in your header and Google doesn't show it, it means Google thinks this meta description is not relevant for search results.

Make sure they are relevant and even then you can't be certain Google thinks they are.

Also, if I understand correctly, you only added meta description to your homepage? Why didn't you add them to other pages too, if you want to see the descriptions poppin up on Google?

Comment: I still can't understand how it would find it relevant for "Stuff Ltd" search, and show my meta description there, but not for "pencils" when that's what I'm talking about in my meta description. 
I am adding them to the other pages and yes they are relevant for each page.